# Read windows xp registry on crashed disk

Tags: windows-xp, registry

My windows xp machine died on me and I have now attached the disk to my new machine. I need to read the registry to get information out (like all my settings for putty).

How do I read the registry on an attached disk in windows xp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-offline-registry-edit.html

Answer (score 2):

In Regedit try:

File ->
Load Hive... ->
Locate file in question from old drive

Or boot from a linux CD and export that way.